# Comment on a post using linkedin api returns 403 Although i have all permissions required

Tags: https, oauth, linkedin-api

i am trying to comment on a post using SocailActions Api 
i am using the following permissions w_organization_social r_organization_social w_member_social 
and i am logged in as a an admin of the page that i am trying to comment on its behalf 
my request is :

```
POST https://api.linkedin.com/v2/socialActions/urn%3Ali%3Ashare%3AXXXXXXXXXX/comments HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Host: api.linkedin.com
cache-control: no-cache,
X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 136

{
   "actor":"urn:li:organization:23741470",
  "object" :"urn:Al:share:6664163994204549120",
   "message":{
      "text":"tessst"
   }
}
```

and i am getting 403

```
{
    "serviceErrorCode": 100,
    "message": "Field Value validation failed in REQUEST_BODY: Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/actor]",
    "status": 403
}
```

the same thing happened when i tried to use the ugcPost Api to post an new comment
any ideas what might cause this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to solve this finally, i remove all header property except the content type and content length then it worked